Sequence of analytic functions on Banach space has a convergent subsequence?
Let $X$ and $Y$ be real or complex Banach spaces and, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $f_{n}: B_{R}(0) \to Y$ is analytic on an open ball $B_{R}(0)$ of radius $R > 0$ around the origin. Suppose $R$ is independent of $n$, so every function $f_{n}$ is analytic on the same ball.
If the sequence $\{f_{n}\}$ is uniformly bounded on $B_{R}(0)$, meaning that there exists a constant $C > 0$ such that $\|f_{n}(x)\| \le C$ for every $x \in B_{R}(0)$, is it true that $\{f_{n}\}$ has a subsequence which converges uniformly to some $f$ on $B_{R}(0)$?
The result seems to be true because it seems to be an abstract version of "bounded sequences have converging subsequences". However, I was not able to find a proof myself. This is not a homework, it is just a question that popped into my mind.

which function would $\sin(\frac{x}{n})$ converge to uniformly?

@Thomas okay so there is some hypothesis missing?

@Thomas to $f(x) = 0$, as ball is bounded. Did you mean $\sin(nx)$?

@mihaild uhmm - yes.
